# Curing concrete in freezing temps

Tags: concrete

I need to pour a few cubic feet of concrete to make a new threshold but the weather forecast indicates temperatures in the low 20s F.

Is that bad for curing concrete?

Answer (score 4):

You'll definitely want to protect the surface of your concrete. I assume that the ground is not frozen. Since the curing process actually generates some heat, only the exposed layer is vulnerable. If it freezes, less water is available to the chemical reaction. This can result in a dry cure, leaving you with a weak, powdery surface.

Cover the pour with poly sheeting and then insulated blankets, straw, or a tent with a *small* heater inside. You can cause similar problems by overheating, so don't do that. Seek to just maintain temperatures above freezing.

Comment: We used to also have 2% calcium added to pours in addition to sheeting and small heaters. The calcium addition helps the mix to cure we had to pull samples for compression testing where the crush them and we never had a failed test with the "hot" mix.+